# Spark Row object instantiated differently from overloaded prototypes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, overloading, type-hinting

The Spark `Row` class in `pyspark/sql/types.py` contains no `__init__`
method, but shows the following overloaded type hints for `__new__`:

```
@overload
def __new__(cls, *args: str) -> "Row"

@overload
def __new__(cls, **kwargs: Any) -> "Row"

def __new__(cls, *args: Optional[str], **kwargs: Optional[Any]) -> "Row"
```

The doc string for `Row` shows various instantiations:

```
>>> Person = Row("name", "age")
>>> row1 = Row("Alice", 11) # This is the one that is hard to understand
>>> row2 = Row(name="Alice", age=11)
>>> row1 == row2
True
```

The *second* line above does not fit any of the overloaded prototypes.
It *almost* fits the prototype with `*args`, except for the fact that all
of the arguments for `*args` are supposed to be *strings*.  This is
obviously not the case for `Row("Alice",11)`, but that invocation
doesn't generate any messages when issued at the REPL prompt.
Obviously, there is something that I am missing about how
type hinting and overloading works.  Can someone please explain?

**P.S.** For context,
I got to this point by trying to see how the constructor
knows that `Row("name","age")` specifies field names while
`Row("Alice", 11)` specifies field values.  The source code for
`__new__` shows that it depends on whether the argument list is
`*args` or `**kwargs`.  Both of the `Row` method invocations in
this paragraph use `*args`, but the
second one simply doesn't fit the prototype for `*args` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row` is a subclass of `tuple` therefore it behaves accordingly. Looking at the source code, I can deduce that the type hints used there do not perform any runtime checks to enforce types (note [1] below provides background on type checking). Therefore, a `Row` object can be created using any object type not just int and strings. Here is one example,

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass


>>> Row(Foo(), Bar())
# <Row(<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5bb3ef4700>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x7f5bb36458d0>)>
```

Creating the row objects using only `args` will not automatically set the `__fields__` parameter. Therefore your assumption that "For context, I got to this point by trying to see how the constructor knows that `Row("name","age")` specifies field names while `Row("Alice", 11)` specifies field values" is incorrect.

Instead by default both will set values of the tuple. This is the reason why `row1 == row2` in your example

```
>>> row = Row('name', 'age')
>>> row.__fields__
# AttributeError: __fields__

>>> row1 = Row("Alice", 11)
>>> row2 = Row(name="Alice", age=11)
>>> row1 == row2
# True
```

One important point here is `Row` also defines `__call__` method which will create a new instance of `Row` from fields and values. Essentially when you call an existing `Row` object in this manner, the existing values become the new assigned fields

```
>>> row = Row('name', 'age')('Alice', 11)
>>> row
# Row(name='Alice', age=11)

>>> row.__fields__
>>> <Row('name', 'age')>
```

But when you use `kwargs` form, the fields and values are automatically set,

```
>>> row = Row(name="Alice", age=11)
>>> row
# Row(name='Alice', age=11)

>>> row.__fields__
# ['name', 'age']
```

**Notes:**

**[1]** [Here](https://realpython.com/python-type-checking) is primer on type hinting and checking.  Third party tools can be used to check the types specified by hints.  This is [not built into IDEs like Spyder](https://dev.to/florimondmanca/comment/4kn0).

Comment: That is extremely illuminating. Thank you. I wish that the functional behaviour was more fleshed out in the doc string. I found that the `__call__` method has some comical side effects: `Row('name', 'age')('Alice', 11)("Blah","Bleh")` yields `Row(Alice='Blah',11='Bleh')`.

Comment: Glad to help. I agree the functional behaviour should have been better. I see a scope for improvement in the code.

Comment: And the doc string! I've been using Matlab for decades, where you can look at the source code, but the documentation was written so that you don't have to. This includes for dataframes and relational algebra. In contrast, Spark's doc strings seem like they target developers, who have no problem delving into the source code to fill in the details of the functional behaviour. It makes it more challenging to spin up quickly.

Comment: Another point of comparison is Microsoft Access's SQL, where there really isn't source code to delve into, and you just need to know SQL (though Access is complicated because it does much more than support SQL). Returning to the point about austere doc strings for PySpark, to be fair, the Python API seems the most extreme in that regard, so it's not the most representative. I recently found that there is a Matlab API for Spark, though without having tried it, it seems more for job submissions than REPL. I probably can't compare the documentation with that of the Python API.